# remix passing args to async server side functions

Tags: remix, remix.run

I am actually a really beginner with this stuff so I beg your pardon for my (silly) questions.

I want to use async functions inside tsx pages, specifically those functions are fetching calls from shopify to get data and ioredis calls to write and read some data.

I know that remix uses action loader functions, so to manage shopify calls I figured out this

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  return json(await GetProductById(params.id as string));
};

async function GetProductById(id: string) {
  const ops = ...;
  const endpoint = ...;
  const response = await fetch(endpoint, ops);
  const json = await response.json();
  return json;
};

export function FetchGetProductById(id: number) {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher.load(`/query/getproductid/${id}`);
  }, []);

  return fetcher.data;
}
```

with this solution I can get the data whenever I want just calling FetchGetProductById, but my problem is that I need to send more complex data to the loader (like objects)

How may I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In Remix, the `loader` only handles GET requests, so data must be in the URL, either via params or searchParams (query string).

If you want to pass data in the body of the request, then you'll need to use POST and create an `action`.

> NOTE: Remix uses `FormData` and not JSON to send data. You will need to convert your JSON into a string.

```js
export const action = async ({ request }: ActionArgs) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const object = JSON.parse(formData.get("json") as string);
  return json(object);
};

export default function Route() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetcher.state !== 'idle' || fetcher.data) return;
    fetcher.submit(
      {
        json: JSON.stringify({ a: 1, message: "hello", b: true }),
      },
      { method: "post" }
    );
  }, [fetcher]);

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(fetcher.data, null, 2)}</pre>
}
```

Comment: Well, I need to call the Route method anywhere in other tsx files, with your solution it returns 405. Using instead fetcher.load and a loader function I am able to do what I meant to do

Comment: I mean I would need an additional step, using a loaderfunction to pass the actionfunction returned data.